# Web sites stop opening - why?

Tags: web-services, browser, jupyter-notebook, localhost, internet-connection

My internet connection behaves in a weird way.
At some point, websites stop opening (I am using Chrome), but the tray icon (Wi-Fi or Lan) indicates that everything is alright, and the TroubleShoot Diagnostics tool tells this as well.

One thing to notice is that when I enter Google search requests at google.com, then it provides me with search results. However, when clicking on any of the search results, then websites do not open.

Sometimes, internet gets "frozen" in this way when I open a Jupyter notebook, which also stops working (which is strange, since it uses localhost at 127.0.0.1:8888).

ping 127.0.0.1 does not show any problems as well, and the file 'hosts' also looks OK (there is the line '127.0.0.1   localhost').

What could be the reason and how else I could trace the problem?

Update: here is the screenshot of the Chrome's development tools (Network tab)
All three error are ERR_TIME_OUT

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have blocked some site/sites with Chrome. You can verify by using a different browser and trying out sites that you can't get to in Chrome.

Another good troubleshooting method is to use Chrome Developer Tools. On Mac, the shortcut is Command+Option+I. Open the developer tools and go to a site that's not working. You should see a bunch of error messages in the console (if the console is not shown, press Esc). Also, go to the 'Network' tab and check if any of the requests are in red.

If the red request status says 'blocked' then open the console back up (Esc button) and click the 3 dots in the top left corner of the console pane. Select 'Request Blocking' and deselect the checkbox that says 'Enable request blocking'

Another possibility is that you've disabled cookies on certain sites. In that case, in the navigation bar, go to [chrome://settings/cookies](http://chrome://settings/cookies) and remove any entries from 'Sites that can never use cookies'

Comment: Actually, all sites but Google.com cannot be opened. The search engine also works by showing me hte search results. I tried Opera as well, and no sites including google.com can be opened there.

Comment: Are you using Windows, MacOS, Linux?

Comment: Windows 10 (64 bit)

Comment: Can you ping another site?
In command prompt, enter:
ping www.bing.com
also, check your firewall settings. Is this a work or personal computer?

Comment: I have deleted all cookies and restarted the computer (which is my personal), and so far the internet works longer than expected, but it is not definite yet whether the problem is solved or not. I will comment once the internet stops working again (very rarely it can work for a day or so and then stop working)

Comment: Make sure to check the 'Network' tab in developer tools and paste any errors you find when the internet starts failing again

Comment: It stopped working again. ping bing.com didn't reveal any issues. I opened the tab Network and tried recording it while refreshing this page. I will add the screenshot shortly